# F# Create type from List

Tags: types, f#, type-conversion

I'm reading data from the console input and want to convert the string I read to custom type. I'm splitting the string I read then trying to instantiate my custom type got a compilation error I don't understand.

**Example of input I'll read (in on one line):**

> 1;Maison de la Prevention Sante;6 rue Maguelone 340000 Montpellier;;3,87952263361082;43,6071285339217

**Code sample:**

```
let input () = Console.In.ReadLine()

type Coordinate = {Longitude:float; Latitude:float}
type Defibrillator = {Name:string; Coordinate:Coordinate} // I only need name and coordinate

let readDefribillator = 
   input().Split(';') 
   |> {Name=""; Coordinate={Longitude=1.0; Latitude=2.0}} // Don't know how to do this
```

**Error (on the line |> {Name=...)**

> This expression was expected to have type 'string [] -> 'a' but here has type 'Defibrillator'

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest

```
open System

type Coordinate = {Longitude:float; Latitude:float}
type Defibrillator = {Name:string; Coordinate:Coordinate} 

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let input  = Console.ReadLine()
    let readDefribillator = 
       input.Split(';') 
       |> fun x -> {Name=""; Coordinate = {
       Longitude = float (x.[4].Replace(",",".")) 
       Latitude =float (x.[5].Replace(",","."))
       }}
    printfn "%A" readDefribillator
    Console.ReadLine |> ignore
    0
```

where

1. `fun x ->` is taking care of the input string array
2. `x.[4]` and `x.[5]` are selecting the coordinates
3. `.Replace(",",".")` is formatting the number as expected by `float`

Comment: Thanks, I like that you explain and the code is really written in a functional way with the use of |>. I still have a long way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this, if you change the commas to dot in the numbers that are input.

```
let readDefribillator =
    let values = input().Split(';')
    { Name = values.[1]; Coordinate = { Longitude = float values.[4]; Latitude = float values.[5] } }
```

If your numbers will contain commas, you can convert using a local or specific culture, with functions Single.Parse, Double.Parse, Convert.ToSingle or Convert.ToDouble. These functions have versions with extra parameters. If you don't use the extra parameters, it appears the local culture will be used, so that you can simply do the following. Commas rather than dots will probably be expected for your locale, but for a US locale this will fail if you input commas. In other words the functions as used here are locale sensitive.

```
let readDefribillator =
    let values = input().Split(';')
    let x = Convert.ToDouble values.[4]
    let y = Convert.ToDouble values.[5]
    { Name = values.[1]; Coordinate = { Longitude = x; Latitude = y } }
```

If you want your input to always be either with comma or with dot, then use the extra parameters of those functions to specify a specific culture. There are predefined cultures. I won't go into all of that here.

Looks like you are starting to learn F#. StackOverflow is not a good place to ask questions like this one. I suggest that instead you join us on https://fsharp.slack.com where pretty much any kind of question is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm indeed starting to learn F#. I'm struggling with the syntax and don't know yet what is available in the framework. It's hard to find but I'm getting there. I didn't think that i could find help on this slack channel. I'll definitely have a look and ask for help. Thanks again for the tip.

Comment: Just in case you haven't discovered it yet, there's this brilliant site, that amounts to an entire book: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com

Comment: I have it's really a nice site. A lot of information, I'll need to read it a few time to digest everything that is written there.